What is the difference between CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::DATE and CURRENT_DATE in PostgreSQL?
I created an immutable function as below:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTIONGetCurrentDate()
RETURNS DATE AS
$p$
BEGIN
    RETURN CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::DATE;
END;
$p$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE SECURITY DEFINER;

And I use this in a UNIQUE INDEX's WHERE clause like:
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX PersonPhoness_UK_PhoneNo_CountryID ON person_phones (phone_no, country_id)
WHERE GetCurrentDate() BETWEEN effective_from_dt AND effective_till_dt;

This unique index does not catch duplicate when another record is added. However, if I change the function to:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetCurrentDate()
  RETURNS DATE AS
$p$
BEGIN
    RETURN CURRENT_DATE;
END;
-- ???

it works. So I want to understand the difference.

You don't show the full function definition that's supposed to work. (Either way, neither can "work".) Also, x-posted to https://stackoverflow.com/q/78364156/939860. Please don't cross-post, especially without declaring as much.

That partial index PersonPhoness_UK_PhoneNo_CountryID cannot "work" because it would need GetCurrentDate() to always return the same result, which obviously it doesn't. Technically the immutable declaration in the function is a lie.
You need to rethink/redesign your model so that it doesn't need a constraint that is true one day and false another day on a row that has not changed.

Thanks @daniel. Yes that is a lie. This needs to be checked when a fresh record is inserted. What is the other option? Nevertheless, CURRENT_DATE is also IMMUTABLE.

@JitendraLoyal: CURRENT_DATE is not immutable. Exactly like CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::date. Either depends on the current timezone setting. And neither can "work" reliably for the case. There is no way around defining the time zone explicitly for which the date is valid one or the other way. Or don't hinge it on dates.
